# imagemagick alternative for blurring image - terminal

Tags: linux

I need a **terminal compatible** program for blurring images ( simple , gaussian type blur will do , zoom and others won't) , that is faster than imagemagick .

I'm currently using imagemagick for providing blurred background lockscreen , but it produces 1-2 secs delay on my machine. Is there any other alternative which could reduce time?

**Update** :
I take current screen's ( all programs open /desktop anything ) screenshot with 'scrot' and then apply imagemagick's convert as :

```
convert /tmp/screenshot.png -blur 0x5 /tmp/screenshotblur.png
```

and then apply that as lockscreen using i3lock. Its pretty popular method , except the time taken by imagemagick is slow. 1-3 secs

Comment: what do you mean that it provides lockscreen ?

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi ,blurred background for my lockscreen :)

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal What is "lockscreen"? Could you add two examples (before and after blur)?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs see updated question :)